# Leyendo archivos de texto en Textbox

Tags: c#, archivo

Estoy deseando trabajar mis aplicaciones con simples archivos de texto. Algo muy simple, colocar un botón y un `TextBox`.

El `TextBox` va a mostrar el contenido del .txt y el botón va a dar la instrucción de que lo cargue.

Trabajo con Visual Studio y con el lenguaje C#.

Ahora bien, logré hacer esto que cuento con el siguiente código:

```
private void btnShowTxt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string texto = File.ReadAllText("test.txt");
  txtShowTxt.Text = texto;
}
```

El problema es que noté que si el archivo test.txt no se encuentro dentro la ruta que me especifica el Visual Studio, me genera una excepción. Yo lo que deseo es que, quien tenga mi aplicación, pueda leer desde la ruta que yo coloque en el código, le cargue en el `TextBox` el contenido del archivo de texto.

Por ejemplo, el usuario coloca el archivo "test.txt" en Documents o lo mueve a Desktop, da igual. No sé por qué el Visual Studio me genera la excepción si no se encuentra el archivo dentro de la carpeta del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Quieres que la aplicación cuando no encuentre dicho archivo lo genere?, para que de esa manera evitar que la aplicación realice una excepción.

Comment: Has pensado en utilizar la clase OpenFileDialog para que te abra una ventana del explorador y poder buscar el fichero? así haces que el usuario seleccione la ruta del fichero de manera cómoda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo que no logro de comprender la necesidad, pero sin duda lo primero que se requiere es validar si el archivo existe en la ruta específicada usando el método [`File.Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists(v=vs.110).aspx) para que no te genere ninguna excepción:

```cs
using System.IO;
```

```
private void btnShowTxt_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string texto = string.Empty;
    string path = "c:\\temp\\test.txt";

    if(File.Exists(path))
        texto = File.ReadAllText(path);
    else
        texto = "Archivo no encontrado";

    txtShowTxt.Text = texto;
}
```

Como tal, Visual Studio o el tipo de solución que uses (consola, escritorio, web, etc.) no cuenta con la funcionalidad para detectar si un archivo ha cambiado de ruta, y en este caso la tendrías que especificar para validar si el archivo existe o no.

Comment: Me sirvió tu respuesta Flxtr. Logré hacer lo que no me salía, que me abra desde la URL que le proporciono al programa que me lea el contenido del txt (test.txt). Ahora lo que quiero saber, es...

Hay forma de que pueda abreviar esta localización?
c:/Users/Fer/Desktop/MyFolder/test.txt

Porque como dije antes, si yo envio esta app a otra persona y contiene esa URL, claramente el nombre del equipo va a cambiar (va a ser de Fer) a otro. Y eso no debería pasar porque no encontraría el archivo.

Answer (score 1):

El lenguaje (al igual que prácticamente todos) busca el archivo en donde le digas que lo busque. En este caso, si le dices que abra un archivo que está en la carpeta del proyecto, el lenguaje buscará el archivo ahí y lo abrirá. Si no está, lanzará una excepción.

Si quieres que el programa abra un archivo desde el escritorio, debes dar la ruta completa al escritorio; por ejemplo: `File.ReadAllText("C:\Usuarios\User\Desktop\test.txt");`.

Obviamente, hacerlo de ese modo no es lo ideal, porque la ruta puede variar entre computadores. En ese caso, el programa debe extenderse para que el usuario introduzca la ruta de su archivo (sea escribiéndola o usando una ventana de selección de archivos), de modo que el programa use esa ruta introducida por el usuario para buscar el archivo ahí.

Comment: El problema es que el compilador me tira error. Me dice que la URL que le proporciono (si coloco el archivo en Desktop o Documents) no encuentra el archivo porque el mismo tiene que estar situado dentro de la carpeta del proyecto. De lo cual no sé cómo solucionar eso. Ese es el problema.

Comment: Como te digo: el archivo se busca en un único sitio: donde le digas. Si no pones una ruta completa, se buscará en la carpeta del proyecto. Si quieres buscarlo en el Escritorio, debes poner la ruta del Escritorio. No puedes decirle al lenguaje "abre el archivo test.txt que se encuentra en cualquier lugar de mi computador". No funciona así. La solución a tu problema es que pongas el archivo en la carpeta del proyecto o que uses la ruta completa al llamar la función ReadAllText.